# How import cordova custom plugin in ionic project?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2, ionic3

I add my custom plugin in my project ionic 3 in this mode:

ionic cordova plugin add /path/to/custom/plugin

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var className: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    className.plugins.ClassName.methodName("======> WORK");
  }
}
```

**plugin.xml**

```
<js-module src="www/ClassName.js" name="ClassName">
<clobbers target="className" />
</js-module>
<platform name="ios">
<config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
<feature name="ClassName">
<param name="ios-package" value="ClassName"/>
</feature>
</config-file>
<header-file src="src/ios/ClassName.h" />
<source-file src="src/ios/ClassName.m" />
</platform>
```

**ClassName.js**

```
function ClassName() {
}
ClassName.prototype.methodName = function(echo, successCallback, errorCallback) {
cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "ClassName", "methodName", [echo]);
};
module.exports = new ClassName();
```

**ClassName.m**

```
#import "ClassName.h"

@implementation ClassName

-(void)methodName:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command {
NSString* echo = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", echo);
}
@end
```

**ClassName.h**

```
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>

@interface ClassName : CDVPlugin
-(void)methodName:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command;
@end
```

I build project and go in xcode to try, but simulator show only black screen and no see log by NSLog...
How i can resolve? What is the correct method to import custom plugins? Thanks

Comment: havent built a plugin.. but you do need to call plugins within `platform.ready().then ()=>{})`

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#ready

Comment: Good! Now work, Thanks.

Comment: great! added it as answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the platform is loaded before calling your plugin.

Use [`platform.ready()`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#ready)

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public platform:Platform) {
    this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
       className.plugins.ClassName.methodName("======> WORK");
    });
  }
```